# How long does the Heroku pgbackups:url last before expiring?

Tags: url, heroku

Heroku states that : "While public, the URL is not guessable and expires after a short duration in order to keep your data secure." for the "heroku pgbackups:url" command.

Does anyone know how long this lasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 10 minutes... The backup is stored on S3, and the returned URL is a signed URL with an `Expires` parameter, which is a Unix timestamp. On OS X, for example, you can inspect the value by converting to an actual date via `date -r [number]`.